# Correct/professional way of logging in ASP.NET apps on IIS server

Tags: iis, logging, asp.net

We're developing an ASP.NET application and have set up a IIS server in our company network for deployment testing. The IIS server is managed by our IT service team and we only have the necessary permissions to publish the ASP.NET app.

Having used log4net in other .NET projects already, I wanted to use it here, too, to get debugging information is something goes wrong on that server. So I asked the IT service team to set up a directory on the server that:

- the IIS server user (IIS APPPOOL) has write permissions to
- we developers have read permissions to
- is not located in the app directory

This resulted in a bit of a back-and-forth between the developers (us) and the IT service team, with them claiming that "this is not the right or professional way to do logging" and we should log to the IIS log instead.

I only found [one question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108282/appender-for-iislog-httpresponse) that inspired us to implement an Appender that calls `Response.AppendToLog` and the logged messaged do appear in the IIS log, but with all whitespaces replaced by "+", which makes stuff like stack traces basically unreadable.

When the application will ultimately be deployed at the customers network, we will certainly need to troubleshoot and debug some errors that will happen, and without debug logs that will be very hard.

So my question is:

Is our IT service team correct and what we're doing is "unprofessional"? And if yes, what is a more professional way of logging for apps running inside IIS server.

Comment: I wouldn't mix application level logs with the IIS logs, way to limited. even the Windows event logs would be a better place. My log framework can log into local files, SQL tables, email, Windows event logs, but not into the http logs. I think your suggested solution is fine and 'professional'.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf log4net has the same capabilities you describe, we also thought about logging to a database or the Windows event log. But telling the customer "Please send me the file xyz.log" is much more convenient and we don't need special permissions for that

Comment: I agree, in my case we are running all the applications on our own servers and are logging into files and a central database.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not correct, it's a classic case of someone asserting a fact which is simply untrue and being unmoving on it since they're the resource owner. You could evidence this by pointing at .NET Core, the latest and greatest iteration of the framework, which comes complete with a logger factory designed to output to anywhere you like - generally a file.

There are a plethora of monitoring tools available that log to files, web apps, databases, you name it. Mixing logs in with IIS Logs or Windows server logs **is** unprofessional, you're taking your separation of concerns and throwing them out the window.

The professional way? Whatever the developer deems as most appropriate in terms of space consumed and clarity of error - the faster you can solve it with the information at hand, the happier your customer will be. If you spend a half hour longer debugging because the code was essentially written in brainfuck your customer will be unhappy.

If your IT department wants to get anal about it, tell them ok, let's do best practice. Ask for the full VSTS suite, a devops guy to come setup your deployment pipelines, get a full suite of app servers and DB servers for dev, uat and prod, etc.etc.etc.

The top and bottom of it is this, you're the developer, you are the authority on this particular subject, it's your application, your errors, your logs.

Comment: Thanks for the support. The IT department actually granted me my request after I asked nicely again, but not without mentioning their "belly ache" with that. So, it seems like all is good. I get my logfile and I didn't make enemies in the IT department by escalating this issue to my department head.